# ionic1 Error: gfs.gracefulify is not a function

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i am trying this command `sudo ionic platform add android` it shows me below error.

```
Error: gfs.gracefulify is not a function
```

My versoin

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Node Version: v4.4.2
```

what happnes i dont know. pls help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/
```

rename the npm-directory to something else.

Now, Cordova will use the global (and hopefully correct) npm.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably related to a quirk/bug in npm 3.x.

Try upgrading to the latest stable node 5.10.1 and reinstalling ionic